# Removing JButtons of certain names from a JPanel

Tags: java

I have a JPanel called tilesLayer, on this panel I use a loop to make a grid of JButtons with their names set to the coordinates like this: X,Y. I need to remove a number of these buttons in a loop. I have a listener set up for when it's a key is pressed it will remove a row. I tried to use the .remove(); method. But I can't seem to find the syntax that will allow me to remove a button called 1,2 or 1,3 or 1,3 and so on. Whats the proper syntax for doing that?

Here's what I figure loop would look like: cullX is  determined earlier in the code, its 48 to be exact. xCord and yCord are already know before hand as well. But obviously the syntax I'm using isn't correct the remove method, and that's what I need to figure out.

```
 while (buttonsRemoved <= cullX) {
        tileLayer.remove(xCord + "," + yCord);
        buttonsRemoved++;
        xCord++;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried. Also tell us what errors you get or what happens when you run your code.

Comment: I've updated my question to give a more clear idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You'll need to get a reference to the JButton you want to remove. You could grab the children and check the text, or you could keep a Map<String, JButton> for looking up JButtons by text.

Comment: You need to pass a `JButton` reference to `tileLayer.remove()`, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the list of components in `tileLayer`.
2. Iterate through the list.
3. For each component, check if it is a `JButton`.
4. If it is, check if its text is the text you are looking for.
5. If it is, remove it from `tileLayer`

Code implementing above algorithm:

```java
java.awt.Component[] components = tileLayer.getComponents();
for (java.awt.Component component : components) {
    if (component instanceof javax.swing.JButton) {
        javax.swing.JButton button = (javax.swing.JButton) component;
        String text = button.getText();
        if (text.equals(xCord + "," + yCord) {
            tileLayer.remove(component);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, maintain a list of JButton references, then you don't have to search.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you maintain a `List<JButton>` with the `JButton` references. You create this list as you add the `JButton`s to your UI. Then you can use the references from this list to remove them from the UI.